# SWITCH in json schema (v5 proposal)

Tags: jsonschema, ajv

I'm newbie about npm [ajv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv)

I have a question:
How many "**switch**" in a object json?
example:

```
var schema = {
  "type": "object",
    "switch": [
        {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                  "powerLevel": {"constant": false}
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "required": ["disbelief"]
            }
        },
        {
            "then": {
                "required": ["confidence"]
            }
        }
    ],
    "switch": [
        {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                  "power": {"constant": false}
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "required": ["disb"]
            }
        },
        {
            "then": {
                "required": ["conf"]
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

I test with schema above in this [link](https://tonicdev.com/57bc1e6db71a5c1400c29467/57d243a6840ccf1400811632)

it's just check end switch.
please help me! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two keywords switch in the same object.

In this particular instance you can merge the "cases" in one switch:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "switch": [
        {
            "if": { "properties": { "powerLevel": {"constant": false} } },
            "then": { "required": ["disbelief"] }
        },
        {
            "if": { "properties": { "power": {"constant": false} } },
            "then": { "required": ["disb"] }
        },
        {
            "then": {
                "oneOf": [
                    { "required": ["confidence"] },
                    { "required": ["conf"] }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In general case you can use keywords allOf, anyOf, oneOf to merge two schemas containing duplicate keywords between them.